# node js Routing not work getting an error on browser

Tags: node.js, express

**Server file:**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose= require('mongoose');

const app=express();

//DB config
const db= require('./config/key').mongoURI;
mongoose.connect(db)
        .then(()=>console.log("successfully Connected to Mongo DB"))
        .catch(err=>console.log(err));

//routes

app.use('api/users', require('./routes/api/user'));
//app.use('api/profile', require('./routes/api/profile'));
//app.use('api/post', require('./routes/api/post'));

app.get('/',(req,res)=> res.json({ msg: 'general Works' }));
;

const port =process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port,()=>console.log("Server is runing on "+ port));
```

**Route file:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', (req, res,next) => res.json({ msg: 'user Works' }));

module.exports = router;
```

When I run the server, it shows the error "Cannot GET /api/users/test" I tried different way but always give above error terminal don't show any error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refactor your code 
from: `app.use('api/users', require('./routes/api/user'));`
to: `app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/user'));`